# Is the ideal $R= (x+y, x−y)$ in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[x, y]$ a prime ideal?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, solution-verification

I wanted to check if my approach is correct:

Consider : $$\phi:\mathbb{C}[x, y] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}[x]$$ $$ y \mapsto -x$$ $$x \mapsto x$$ is a surjective homomorphism, with  $\ker(\phi)=(x+y)$. Hence, $\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(x+y) \cong \mathbb{C}[x]$. Now, I use the third isomorphism theorem to assert that $\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(x+y,x-y) \cong (\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(x+y))/\overline{(x-y)}$, where bar denotes passage to the quotient ring. This is the approach described in Artin, and the part I'm least confident about. So, what I do now is, consider the image of the ideal $I=(x-y)$ under the substitution homomorphism described above and quotient $\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(x+y)$ with the ideal $\phi(I)$, i.e the principal ideal generated by the image of $(x-y)$. Note that $\phi(I)=(\phi(x-y))=(x-\phi(y))=(x+x)=(2x)$ and hence, $\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(x+y,x-y) \cong \mathbb{C}[x]/(2x)$, which is clearly not a domain, and hence $R=(x+y,x-y)$ is not prime.

Does this look alright?

Comment: $\Bbb C [x]/(2x)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb C$, which is a field. Anyway, you can easily see that $(x+y, x-y) = (x,y)$ which is obviously a maximal ideal.

Comment: @Crostul yes of course, silly me. $2$ is invertible over $\mathbb{C}$. What if the question were modified to $\mathbb{Z}[x]$? Here, $2$ is not invertible and hence $(2x) \neq (x)$.

Comment: You are right: over $\Bbb Z$ it wouldn't be a prime ideal.